# How to make a complex shape with round elements with parametrically adjustable dimensions?

Tags: modeling

I got the following  parametric sketch from SolidWorks.
It's an oval shape with the end and bottom cut of, in the corners there are radii.

[image]

Can I make this shape fully changeable with shapekeys?

Basically I want to change every dimension I put on the picture in a non destructive way but changeable, by shapekeys or other means
[image]

Bottom picture is the body that with the dimensions that can be changed, keeping its relations intact.
[image]

Comment: Don't you think it might be a good idea to define what you need it to be "fully changeable" *to*? What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Its an oval, it can be two circels intercutting eachother, cutoff by the height and the radius.

Comment: Basicly I want to change every dimension I put on the picture in a non destructive way but changable, by shapekeys or other means

Comment: dimensions. I'm from the CAD world. But I have allot of design that are parametric. One example is this one. It has many features I desire. You can solve it mathematicly but I wonder if blender hasn't got the capability allready.

Comment: is it supposed to be a flat surface ? How is it supposed to look as a 3D object? Also, please show a second shape you're thinking of so that we can test

Comment: you can extrude it. but underlaying in solidworks you can change the sketch so when it rebuilds you have a dimenal new object. I would like to do something like that in blender